# Clarification on Binary file (PE/COFF & ELF) formats & terminology

Tags: windows, linux, assembly, elf, portable-executable

I'm confusing little in terminology.

> A file that is given as input to the linker is called **Object File**.
> The linker produces an **Image file**, which in turn is used as input by the loader.

I got this from "MS PE & COFF Specification"

**Q1.** Image file is also referred to as `Binary Image`, `Binary File` or just `Binary`. Right?

**Q2.** So, according to the above stated terminology, the PE/ELF/COFF are the formats of *Image File* & not the *Object File.* right? But http://www.sco.com/developers/gabi/latest/ch4.intro.html says

> This chapter describes the object file format, called ELF (Executable and Linking Format). There are three main types of object files.
>
> - *A relocatable file* holds code and data suitable for linking with other
>   object files to create an executable
>   or a shared object file.
> - *An executable file* holds a program suitable for execution; the
>   file specifies how exec(BA_OS) creates
>   a program's process image.
> - *A shared object file* holds code and data suitable for linking in two
>   contexts. First, the link editor [see
>   ld(BA_OS)] processes the shared object
>   file with other relocatable and shared
>   object files to create another object
>   file. Second, the dynamic linker
>   combines it with an executable file
>   and other shared objects to create a
>   process image.

contradictorily he is saying that both Object File &  Image File are ELF formats & He is not at all differentiating between object & image files but referring them commonly as Object files. Isn't it wrong?

**Q3.** I know that PE is derived from COFF. But why does the Microsoft specifications of PE format is named *Microsoft Portable Executable "and Common Object File Format Specification"*. Do they still support COFF? If they, in which OS? I thought PE completely replaced COFF long ago.

Comment: On second reading, I'm not exactly sure what your question is - are you asking about what the differences are between PE, COFF, and ELF, how linking/loading works and how addresses are resolved, or something else?

Comment: I segmented my question into 2 questions: the other question on `VA & RVA` is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170843/va-virutual-adress-rva-relative-virtual-address

Comment: @Michael Burr: 1. I'm confused with the terminology differences of `object file` & `Image file` used in both PE/COFF & ELF specifications.
 2. Sticking to ther above stated `object file` & `Image file` terminology, do the `object files` are also in PE/COFF format (on windows) &  ELF format (on linux)?

Comment: @ Michael Burr: Is it you who posted the answer and deleted it? If its you, please repost the answer, as it addresses clearly my first part of the query.

Comment: @claws: I undeleted my answer. But just for reference, I deleted it initially because it seemed to largely be restating information you had in your question instead of answering it.

Comment: @Michael Burr: My post is just `Clarification`(see title) :). Just wanted to make sure, I got this right. :D

Answer (score 23, accepted):

*I'm the OP. Every one's answer is a partial answer. So, I'm combining all the other answers with what I learnt to complete the answer.*

This is the "**Generally**" used terminology.

- A file that is given as input to the linker (output of assembler) is called `Object File` or `Relocatable File`.
- The linker produces an `Image file`, which in turn is used as input by the loader. Now, an `Image file` can either be an `Executable file` or `Library file`. These 'Library files' are of two kinds:

  1. Static Library (*.lib files for windows. *.a for linux)
  2. Shared/Dynamic libraries : `DLL` ( *.dll on windows) & `Shared Object file`( *.so in Linux)
- The term `Binary File` / `Binary` can be used to refer to either an ObjectFile or an ImageFile. Undestand depending up on the context. It is a very general term.
- Loader when loads the image file into memory. Then it is called `Module` (I'm not sure about Linux guys, but windows guys call it `Module`

http://www.gliffy.com/pubdoc/1978433/L.jpg
[alt text http://www.gliffy.com/pubdoc/1978433/L.jpg](http://www.gliffy.com/pubdoc/1978433/L.jpg)

As I said, these are "**Generally**" used terminology. There are no strict definitions for the terms 'binary file', 'image file', or 'object file'.

Particularly the term 'object file' might sometimes be used to mean an intermediate file output by the compiler for use by the linker, but in another context might mean an executable file.

Especially on different platforms they might be used for refer to different or similar things. Even when discussing issues on a single platform, one writer might use the terms somewhat differently than another.

- Both ObjectFile & ImageFile are in PE Format in windows & ELF format in linux.
- ELF is not only the format of the image file but is also the format of the object file.
- Every ELF file starts with an ELF Header. The second field of an ELF Header is `e_type`; this fields lets us know whether the file is an object file (aka a relocatable in ELF parlance), or an image (which can be either an executable or a shared object) or something else (core file's are also ELF files).
- I don't know if there is any bit in header that differentiates an Object file  from Image file. It needs to be checked.

> I know that PE is derived from COFF.
>   But why does the Microsoft
>   specifications of PE format is named
>   Microsoft Portable Executable "and
>   Common Object File Format
>   Specification". Do they still support
>   COFF? If they, in which OS? I thought
>   PE completely replaced COFF long ago.

As far as "PE" vs "COFF", my recollection is that Microsoft use the "COFF" specification as the starting point for the "PE" specification but extended it for their needs. So strictly speaking a "PE" file isn't a "COFF" file, but it's very similar in many ways.

Comment: Actually, whether the term *module* is used to describe a loaded PE image depends on the context. It is a common term in the Image Loader in user mode, because it makes sense to describe symbol dependencies between an EXE and a DLL or between two DLLs in terms of dependencies between modules. However, from the kernel-mode memory manager's point of view (when describing section and segment objects), loaded images are still just referred to as *images*, because it does not make sense to describe the memory mappings in terms of *modules*

Comment: It looks like one of the image links is dead, does anybody know what the image used to be? I can't find it on archive.org.

Comment: 'Static libraries' are input to the *linker*, not the *loader*. These are essentially an archive of individual object files with some contents-table at the header.

Answer (score 3):

There are no strict definitions for the terms 'binary file', 'image file', or 'object file'.

Particularly the term 'object file' might sometimes be used to mean an intermediate file output by the compiler for use by the linker, but in another context might mean an executable file.

Especially on different platforms they might be used for refer to different or similar things. Even when discussing issues on a single platform, one writer might use the terms somewhat differently than another.

As far as "PE" vs "COFF", my recollection is that Microsoft use the "COFF" specification as the starting point for the "PE" specification but extended it for their needs. So strictly speaking a "PE" file isn't a "COFF" file, but it's very similar in many ways.

Answer (score 1):

gcc -c will produce a .o file, which is an elf format object file, on a Linux system. "ELF 32-bit LSB relocatable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV)" is how a .o file is described by the file command on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to Q2 for ELF, ELF is not only the format of the image file but is **also** the format of the object file.

Every ELF file starts with an [ELF Header](http://www.sco.com/developers/gabi/1998-04-29/ch4.eheader.html).  The second field of an ELF Header is `e_type`; this fields lets us know whether the file is an object file (aka a relocatable in ELF parlance), an image (which can be either an executable or a shared object) or something else (core file's are also ELF files).

Comment: awesome!! thats, a valuable piece of info. Do you know if its similar case with PE also?

Comment: Yes, it appears from this document (http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/system/platform/firmware/PECOFF.mspx) that PE does something similar ("At the beginning of an object file, or immediately after the signature of an image file, is a standard COFF file header").

Comment: I didn't mean the PE header. I know that PE file has a header. I was asking about about such a flag bit. Does PE too have any flag that differentiates ObjectFile from an ImageFile.

Answer (score 0):

As an aside, I know core dumps on Solaris (and I am guessing other Unix flavors) can be in ELF format.