# Why typecast a pointer at its declaration?

Tags: c, pointers, embedded

Not sure if I'm phrasing the question properly nor how to best explain what I'm trying to have answered so bear with me.

When defining a microcontroller register, you would write something like this:

`#define io_register (*(volatile unsigned char *)0x25)`

I also found this line of code here: [Pass a hex address to a Pointer Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819569/pass-a-hex-address-to-a-pointer-variable)

`int *pointer = (int *) 0x00010010;`

I understand that a pointer that points at an int is being declared left of the = sign, but why is there a typecast **(int *)** right of it?

Same with the **#define**, I understand that the value at 0x25 is being dereferenced but why am I not able to write it like this:

`#define io_register *(0x25)`

or

`int *pointer = 0x25;`

What am I missing here? Please feel free to rephrase or correct any mistakes I've made, still trying to wrap my head around pointers and registers.

Comment: Tell me can you do this:- `float var = "abc";`?

Comment: @Lucas yes you can.

Comment: @Lucas it will store in float the reference to string literal. If you cast `float var = (float)"abc";` you will suppress the warning.

Comment: My beloved brother @P__J__ , after writing this expression into my code, i'll not get the **`warning`**, i'll get an error stating that `error: incompatible types when initializing type 'float' with type 'char *'`.

Comment: @P__J__ Even if I typecast the string literal. After typecasting we'll get `error: pointer value used where a floating point value was expected`
So, tell me what are you talking about _"it will store in float the reference to string literal."_?

Comment: As for microcontroller registers specifically, in order to access such a register portably, you have to cast an absolute address to a pointer and then de-reference it, because that's the only mechanism C offers to access a specific address. Embedded system compilers often provide non-standard options to declare a variable at an absolute address, like @ or #pragma, but those aren't standard nor portable.

Comment: "_... why is there a typecast *(int ) right of it?_" - there isn't; you cannot deference an `int` and the cast is `(int*)` in any case which is entirely different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cast  suppresses the warning. That is its role in those statements. Otherwise it will be casted implicit way, and warning omitted. No difference in the code or program execution.

---

`#define io_register *(0x25)`

`*(0x25)` will not be a pointer in any circumstanes and `io_register` when used means : multiply by 0x25.

```
int x = 10 io_register;
```

which means: `int x = 10 *(0x25);`

Comment: Just to clarify something, 0x25 can be written as a int value in C? I.e. binary hex etc?

And can I perform bitshifting and such on ints containing a hexadecimal or binary value?

Comment: 0x25 it is integer constant and it is an integer value. the is no diferenece between 16, 0x10, 020 0b10000  (0b is a gcc extension).

Comment: Yeah, just tried shifting some 0b value and printing them as %d so I get what you mean. Thanks for the help!

Comment: "Otherwise it will be casted implicit way" This is incorrect. First, a cast is always explicit, you mean conversion. Second, if you don't cast, the code is invalid C since it doesn't sate the constraints of simple assignment.

Comment: `int * pointer = 0x25;` is invalid C, it's a constraint violation. A compiler must produce a diagnostic message. Nothing "implicit" should happen, that's non-conforming/non-standard extensions.

Comment: @Lundin  it is a constraint violation - but the code is still valid. I do not know any compiler which emits the error here. Tested today iar. keil, green hills

Comment: That's just the usual issue of warnings vs errors and what should block the code from producing a binary - such things are beyond the scope of the C language. Popular compilers like gcc and clang blocks invalid C from compiling if you use `-pedantic-errors`. If you don't, they will just give a warning and produce a non-conforming binary. If you just compile with the default, such as gnu11, then gnu11 is what you get, not c11.

Comment: Embedded system compilers are likely more lenient, though just for the record I found one which doesn't allow it. Codewarrior gives "error: type mismatch (expected int*, given int)". This is fully conforming behavior.

Answer (score 2):

An important prerequisite of any assignment operation is data type compatibility. In other words, the data type of the equation's `(int *pointer = 0x25;)` *LHS* `(int *pointer)` must be compatible with whatever data type results from the evaluation of the equation's *RHS* `(0x25)`.

For example, if both *LHS* and *RHS* are **`int`** types, then there will be no problem assigning the integer value of *RHS to LHS*.

But, in this expression:

> int *pointer = 0x25;

you have **`int *`** data type in *LHS* and **`int`** data type in *RHS*. So, there's an incompatibility between *LHS & RHS*. That's why you need to cast *RHS* to **`(int *)`**.

Comment: Must not. Should be. And compiler will ask (using warning): `dude! Are you sure?`. When you explicitly cast you answer `Yes I am, my compiler friend`

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't get you. @P__J__

Comment: If you're about this exp. `int *pointer = 0x25`. then you know, everyone is aware that we can't provide a memory address to the pointer manually.

Comment: @P__J__ This answer is correct. The compiler may as well give an error as a warning, as long as it gives some manner of diagnostic. The reason for this isn't "are you sure", but "this is invalid C, would you like a non-standard extension?" For details see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52186834/pointer-from-integer-integer-from-pointer-without-a-cast-issues

Answer (score 1):

The cast is needed because `0x00010010` is not a pointer but an integer (it is the first type among `int`, `unsigned int` or `long int` that can represent the value 65552) .

Only integer constant expressions having value of **`0`** can be converted to a pointer implicitly (i.e. without a cast); the resulting pointer would be a null pointer.

---

You can naturally write

```
#define io_register *(0x25)
```

but you cannot *use* that `io_register` to access memory at address 0x25, because that `0x25` is not a pointer - it is an integer.

In C one does not really access addresses; instead one dereferences pointers to get *lvalues* that designate an *object*, and then get the value of that object, or a set a new value to it.

Comment: You can use it of course for example `int x = 5 io_register;` and `io_register` means "multiply by 0x25

Answer (score 1):

With

```
int *pointer = (int *) 0x00010010;
```

You are telling the pointer to point to an absolute address in memory, the value at that address can be dereferenced with `*pointer`.

With

```
int *pointer = 0x25;
```

The compiler does not like that because 0x25 is an integer but pointer is not an integer, it is an integer pointer.