# function address in .pdb is different from .exe,why?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windbg, dbghelp

i read the address of my main function from .pdb file by SymEnumSymbols,the value is        **0x0100116e0** ,

```
BOOL CALLBACK SymEnumSymbolsProc(PSYMBOL_INFO pSymInfo, ULONG SymbolSize, PVOID UserContext )
{   
    if( pSymInfo != NULL )
    {
        // Show the symbol      

        std::string str = pSymInfo->Name;
        if (str.find("main")!=-1)
        {
            int ss=pSymInfo->Address;
        }


    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

but this function's address in VS2008's dissamble code is  004116E0

```
int _tmain( int argc, const TCHAR* argv[] )
{
    004116E0  push        ebp  
    004116E1  mov         ebp,esp 
    ...
{
```

then i tried to verify the result by passing the 2 different address to SymGetSymFromAddr64, i got the same funcitun symbol expectedly,the only difference was the address member of PIMAGEHLP_SYMBOL64,one was 100116e0 while the other was 4116E0.
i also tried to verify it by microsoft's dbh.exe ,the command is

```
load TestSymbolLookup.pdb
TestsymbolLookup [1000000]:n main
addr   : 10116e0
name   : main
size   : b2c
flags  : 0
type   : 2
modbase: 1000000
value  : 0
reg    : 0
scope  : SymTagExe<1>
tag    : SymTagFunction<5>
index  :1
```

my main function's address is unique in the TestsymbolLookup.exe,but why did i get 2 different answers???

Answer (score 5):

Those addresses are the "same", they differ because the one in the PDB is the relative virtual address, while the one you are finding with the enum proc has be virtualized. The PDB will always use an address that cannot be obscured by rebasing etc.

If you subtract the based loading address (or the start of the `.code` section depending), you'll get the RVA. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170843/va-virtual-adress-rva-relative-virtual-address) SO question may prove to be useful to read.