# What is the Initial Values of IAT (Import Address Table) Stand for?

Tags: c, windows, dll, linker, portable-executable

In PE header, there are import directory which describes where the loader should bind the imported symbols. More precisely:

```
typedef struct _IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR {
    union {
        DWORD   Characteristics;
        DWORD   OriginalFirstThunk;
    } DUMMYUNIONNAME;
    DWORD   TimeDateStamp;
    DWORD   ForwarderChain;
    DWORD   Name;
    DWORD   FirstThunk;
} IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR;
typedef IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR UNALIGNED *PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR;
```

The `FirstThunk` field is the RVA of binding point, which is located in IAT (i.e., the `.idata` section).

Usually, the linker would generates some initial values on `.idata`. I thought that those are useless, until I realized that if I wipe the entire `.idata` out, the DLL would fail to load. This is because the loader did not bind the import symbols, and results in access violation when the program trying to call these imported APIs.

My question is, why there are initial values in IAT? Is it necessary for DLL loading? I thought that prodving by the import directory should be sufficient for loader to bind the imports.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why PE need Original First Thunk(OFT)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42413937/why-pe-need-original-first-thunkoft)

Comment: @500-InternalServerError
Many thanks, but I am still wondering why this OFT cannot be zero-outed. From the answers of the question, if OFT fails, the loader should fallback to "the normal way" and resolve the import symbols via import directory. However, if we wipe out the OFT, then the loader would fail.

Comment: It seems OP asks FirstThunk's initial value, not OFT. I think it's *Hint* which points to ordinal.

Comment: Okay, got it - slight misfire.

Comment: @couyoh No, I think OP is confused about the terms. I guess he is asking why Import Lookup Table (OFT) is needed for import resolving.

Comment: @jtxkopt I am asking the position pointed by `FirstThunk`, the Import Address Table. Not the Import Lookup Table nor the `FirstThunk`.

Comment: IAT holds some initial values, and if I wipe out the IAT, the DLL fails to load. I am wondering how could this happen.

Comment: Which initial values do you mean exactly? The contents of IAT is the same as ILT before the import resolving. By *wiping out*, do you mean *zeroing out* the contents of IAT? or removing the IAT completely? If you remove that, of course, it doesnt work.

Comment: Yes, but wiping out I meant zero out.

Comment: Typo: but -> by

Comment: @jtxkopt Only zero out makes the DLL loader fails. Even if I fill the IAT with random values, the loader was still able to load the DLL successfully.

Comment: I have no idea how could this happen.

Comment: Because the loader uses the last zero entry as NULL terminator. If you zero out all the table, then it means the table is empty and causes the loader to stop the import resolving and to fail.

Comment: @jtxkopt Yes but if the loader make use of ILT, what is the point to read from the IAT?

Comment: And, sometimes the loader could still resolve some part of the IAT after zero out the table.

Comment: The Loader writes the RVA of the resolved imports into the entries of IAT. It doesn't read actually. It might be needed for the Loader to know when it stops to write the RVAs using NULL entry. So, if you zero out the IAT, it could be end with unexpected results.

Comment: Yeah, I think it's not necessary to read from the IAT. Perhaps the loader asserts that IAT is a copy of ILT, and somehow use them to load the DLL, just like what you said. Wondering if there are some spec or conventions for linkers to generate IAT.