# gdb prints invalid address of static const arrays of non-string values for classes with virtual functions

Tags: c++, gdb

**EDIT:** Please scroll down to the "EDIT" section at the end of the question for more recent details. I'm not editing the rest of this post to preserve history of the comments.

I have a class defined like so in a header file:

```
class TestClass
{
public:
  TestClass() { }
  ~TestClass() { }
  void Test();
private:
  static const char * const carr[];
  static const int iarr[];
};
```

The `TestClass::Test()` function just makes sure that both arrays are used so they're not optimized away - prints them to log. I won't post it here for clarity. Arrays are initialized in .cpp file.

Above case works fine, when creating an instance of this class, the addresses look like so:

```
t   TestClass * 0x20000268  
    carr    const char * const[]    0x8002490 <TestClass::carr> 
    iarr    const int []    0x800249c <TestClass::iarr>
```

Memory addresses beginning with `0x20...` belong to RAM region, while `0x80...` belong to ROM/Flash. As expected, both arrays get placed in ROM.

However if I add `virtual` qualifier to any function in the class, e.g. its destructor like so:

```
class TestClass
{
public:
  TestClass() { }
  virtual ~TestClass() { }
  void Test();
private:
  static const char * const carr[];
  static const int iarr[];
};
```

Then the result is this:

```
t   TestClass * 0x20000268  
    carr    const char * const[3]   0x80024b4 <TestClass::carr> 
    iarr    const int [1000]    0x20000270
```

In particular - `iarr` is placed in RAM which is totally not what I expected.

This file is compiled like so:

```
arm-none-eabi-g++ -mcpu=cortex-m7 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=soft -O0 -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -ffreestanding -fno-move-loop-invariants -Wall -Wextra -g3 -DDEBUG -DUSE_FULL_ASSERT -DTRACE -DOS_USE_TRACE_ITM -DSTM32F767xx -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DHSE_VALUE=24000000 -I../include -I../system/include -I../system/include/cmsis -I../system/include/stm32f7-hal -std=gnu++11 -fabi-version=0 -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fno-use-cxa-atexit -fno-threadsafe-statics -c -o "src\\main.o" "..\\src\\main.cpp"
```

And the linking part:

```
arm-none-eabi-g++ -mcpu=cortex-m7 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=soft -O0 -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -ffreestanding -fno-move-loop-invariants -Wall -Wextra  -g3 -T mem.ld -T libs.ld -T sections.ld -nostartfiles -Xlinker --gc-sections -L"../ldscripts" -Wl,-Map,"VirtualClassTestF7.map" --specs=nano.specs -o "VirtualClassTestF7.elf" "@objs.rsp"
```

There are more files built in this project, related to hardware initialization. I don't include those to keep the post short.

Is there any switch that controls this behavior? I've already tried the obvious parts that I could come up with, which could have a slightest connection with the issue:

- Optimization levels: O0, O1, O2, O3, Os, Ofast
- Removing `-ffunction-sections` and `-fdata-sections`
- Adding `-fno-common`
- Making the array larger to go over some threshold if there was some. I've made its size 10k elements (times sizeof(uint32_t)) and it was still in RAM
- Trying three different versions of toolchain

Toolchain is `arm-none-eabi`. Tried versions (outputs of `arm-none-eabi-gcc --version`):

- arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 4.9.3 20150529 (release) [ARM/embedded-4_9-branch revision 224288]
- arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe (bleeding-edge-toolchain) 7.2.0
- arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe (bleeding-edge-toolchain) 8.3.0
- Cygwin (gcc (GCC) 7.4.0)

First one comes from official ARM website: https://developer.arm.com/open-source/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm/downloads. Last two come from http://www.freddiechopin.info/en/download/category/11-bleeding-edge-toolchain as ARM officially doesn't release 64-bit version and our project grew to size that breaks the 32-bit version.

Why this is an issue and why I'm specifically looking into a compiler switch: Possibly there is another way to force those values into ROM by writing it a bit differently. This is not an option - we've encountered this issue recently in a larger project spanning thousands of files where class inheritance is used heavily in various places. Catching all the possible occurrences of such arrays (some being created with macros, some by external tools) and then reorganizing all that code is out of the question. Therefore I'm looking for a reason why the compiler behaves in this exact way and what are the possible solutions that don't involve touching the source files.

**EDIT:** It appears to be some kind of issue with gdb and how it retrieves the address of that variable, or I'm missing something. I went ahead and created the same example on PC (Cygwin gcc 7.4.0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

class TestClass
{
public:
  TestClass() { }
  virtual ~TestClass() { }
  static const char * const carr[];
  static const int iarr[];
};

const char * const TestClass::carr[] = {
    "test1", "test2", "test3"
};

const int TestClass::iarr[] = {
    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0
};

int main() {
  TestClass instance;
  printf("instance: %p, carr: %p, iarr: %p\n", &instance, instance.carr, instance.iarr);
  fflush(stdout);
  while(1);
  return 0;
}
```

The output of the program is this:

```
instance: 0xffffcba8, carr: 0x100403020, iarr: 0x100403040
```

This is also confirmed by the map file. Relevant portion:

```
 .rdata         0x0000000100403000       0xa0 ./src/main.o
                0x0000000100403020                TestClass::carr
                0x0000000100403040                TestClass::iarr
```

However gdb shows this:

```
p instance.iarr
$2 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0}
p &instance.iarr
[New Thread 57872.0x4f28]
$3 = (const int (*)[10]) 0x60003b8a0
p &instance.iarr
$4 = (const int (*)[10]) 0x60003b8d0
```

And what's even more interesting is that this address changes every time I attempt to print it with gdb. What's the reason for this?

Question title and tags adjusted.

Comment: I am afraid, this will be one of those questions with high vote count and no answer. You might want to ask directly in gcc mailing list, as I am afraid general population here will have no knowledge of those quite arcane things.

Comment: Why does your second output show the arrays' sizes but the first one does not? Could it be that `iarr[1000]` is too big for ROM and it was therefore placed into RAM?

Comment: Please add some information regarding the used toolchain and target, as it's not possible to reproduce the issue

Comment: @rozina This is how Eclipse shows this to me. For the target I use ROM (2MB) is much larger than available RAM (0.5MB). Despite that, linker would return an error if data did not fit into ROM.

Comment: @YannDroneaud Question edited with additional information

Comment: What about the pointers contained in `carr`?  Do they point to ROM or RAM?

Comment: You just need to specify the appropriate section with the `section("section-name")` attribute. The right section name appears probably in a linker script.

Comment: @FlorianWeimer Post edited. Appears to be gdb related. Values seem to be correctly placed in `.rdata`, according to map file or "manually" printed addresses.

Comment: Have you thought about VA and VRA? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170843/va-virtual-address-rva-relative-virtual-address  When you load up your program to memory addres your addresses aren't read as they are in your software. Think of them as an offset of sorts.  So there is a possibility that you are loading your object it is offsetted of VA of some point, therefore your memory addresses have different value but same offset.

Answer (score 1):

gdb copies your array into RAM, you don't even need an instance for it, a class with a vtable is enough:

```
(gdb) p TestClass::iarr
$1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
(gdb) p (int*)TestClass::iarr
$2 = (int *) 0x7ffff7a8b780
(gdb) p *(int *) 0x7ffff7a8b780 @ 100
$3 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0 <repeats 94 times>}
(gdb) p (int*)TestClass::iarr
$4 = (int *) 0x7ffff7a8b7a0
(gdb) p (int*)TestClass::iarr
$5 = (int *) 0x7ffff7a8b7c0
(gdb) p *(int *) 0x7ffff7a8b780 @ 100
$6 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0 <repeats 78 times>}
```

I guess this boils down to gdb's interpretation of "C". If you need the real address in gdb, you need a function that returns it.

Comment: That's what I've noticed as well - the array under that address was actually there. Is this documented anywhere? Is there a way to turn it off?