# What's the difference between elf_i386 and i386linux?

Tags: architecture

```
GNU ld version 2.17.50.0.6-14.el5 20061020
  Supported emulations:
   elf_x86_64
   elf_i386
   i386linux
```

Anyone knows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I though they were the same. Are you on i386? Maybe it's just a naming convenience.

Answer (score 0):

See also [Clarification on Binary file (PE/COFF & ELF) formats & terminology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170818/clarification-on-binary-file-pe-coff-elf-formats-terminology)

The first 2 are obviously 32 and 64 bit versions of [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format), the third one I haven't heard of

Comment: The only exe formats I have heard of on linux are coff & elf - there might be some other odd formats on non-x86 hw