# What is the format of .o Object Files?

Tags: c++, c, windows, compilation, object-files

I've been learning low-level stuff for a while now and I'm quite familiar with PE files and how they work. But I've been unable to find any documentation of their precursor `.o` files. I'm looking for a deep-dive on the actual byte-by-byte structure of them.

What does the format of `.o` files depend on? Is it even platform specific at all? Perhaps compiler-specific?  Where can I find documentation on the file format of `.o` files? Mostly interested in Windows.

Comment: https://wiki.osdev.org/COFF https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format

Comment: Read Levine's book *Linkers and loaders*

Comment: To my knowledge, the object file are not platform-specific, but not all compilers use the same formats. MSVC uses a different format than GCC/Clang on Windows.

Comment: This could answer your question: [clarification-on-binary-file-pe-coff-elf-formats-terminology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170818/clarification-on-binary-file-pe-coff-elf-formats-terminology) ; `.o` aka `object` aka `relocatable` files are platform specific (ie executable file format). you will find some infos here [Comparison_of_executable_file_formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_executable_file_formats)

Answer (score 2):

`.o` files as produced by GCC and LLVM when using Windows (MinGW) are COFF files (see https://wiki.osdev.org/COFF). On certain other platforms the ELF format is used.

The Windows PE format (used for `.dll` and `.exe` files) is actualy a subset of the COFF format.